# Convert HTML blob to DOCX blob

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, node.js

The goal of my app is to export what I'm seeing on screen to docx file.

1 solution I came up with was copying to clipboard then using "html-to-docx" or "html-docx-js" to convert the HTML blob to docx blob.

This solution works partially because the output style whether I'm copying to clipboard and pasting in Word or simply using the packages is different.

The outcome I'm looking for is like copying and pasting directly but with code.

Code of copying the html:

```
const handleCopyToClipboard = () => {
    const contentElement = contentRef.current;
    if (contentElement) {
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(contentElement);
        const htmlContent = contentElement.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
        const tempElement = document.createElement('div');
        tempElement.innerHTML = htmlContent;
        const tables = tempElement.querySelectorAll('table');
        tables.forEach(table => {
            const rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr'));
            const tsvData = rows.map(row => {
                const cells = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('th, td'));
                return cells.map(cell => cell.textContent).join('\t');
            }).join('\n');
            table.setAttribute('data-tsv', tsvData);
        });
        document.body.appendChild(tempElement);
        window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
        const tempRange = document.createRange();
        tempRange.selectNode(tempElement);
        window.getSelection()?.addRange(tempRange);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
        tempElement.remove();
        tables.forEach(table => table.removeAttribute('data-tsv'));
        message.success('Copied to clipboard!', 4);
    }
```

Code of using the copied content:

```
const getDocs = async ()=>{
    let htmlData = ''
    const clipboardContents = await navigator.clipboard.read()
    for (const item of clipboardContents) {
        for (const type of item.types) {
            if (type.includes("html")){
                const htmlBlob = await item.getType(type)
                htmlData = await htmlBlob.text()
            }
        }
    }

    const fileBuffer = await HTMLtoDOCX(htmlData)
    saveAs(fileBuffer, 'html-to-docx.docx');
}
getDocs()
```

perhaps anyone knows a good solution for reaching the same output?

Comment: _"The goal of my app is to export what I'm seeing on screen to docx file."_ - May I ask **why** you want to do that? `.docx` is a terrible format for technical documentation...

Comment: sure! it is a Requirement from my team leader. I'm stuck on this bit a whole day.